# Is there any way to extract compile_commands.json from MSBuild?

Tags: windows, compilation

is there a way to extract the compilation database as compile_commands.json file with MSBuild on Windows?
Cmake based project allow you calling by:

```
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
```

How to solve or produce with MSBuild?

Comment: also look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68724763/717355 if using `CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have found--> Visual Studio allows you to perform via a plugin called Sourcetrail. It can be installed as extensions.